# What kind of converter is needed for video HDMI to DVI-D?

Tags: hdmi, conversion, dvi, display-adapter

I need to connect my DVD player with HDMI output to a monitor which has only VGA and DVI-D ports.

On eBay there's this cheap HDMI to DVI-D adapter:
http://www.ebay.com/itm/DVI-D-24-1-pin-male-plug-to-HDMI-female-Video-Converter-Adapter-for-HDTV-DVD-PC-/141071709897?hash=item20d88776c9:g:MH4AAMXQ9y9SNzDk
[image]

Is a simple adapter like this, all that's needed to make the conversion?
Or do I need an actual signal converter to do the job?

Comment: That adapter is all that you need.

Comment: @DrZoo I remember an issue with a raspberry pi and a vga-hdmi adaptor needing a power supply  .. doug's post and bavara's response https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=91&t=24504   it probably doesn't apply to the OP but for whatever reason, it seemed necessary to have a powered adaptor in the instance in that link.

Comment: @DrZoo also with simple looking USB-Ps2 adaptors,  if a person has a ps2 keyboard and tries to adaptor that to USB, it won't work(unless perhaps it's a very unusual ps2 keyboard).  So just because an adaptor has the right connectors on them doesn't always mean it will work.  So perhaps that thing will work, but you should really justify why it will work..  You shouldn't just expect the guy asking the question to accept what you say based on your "authority".

Comment: @barlop the Pi forum you linked is a HDMI to VGA issue. HDMI lacks VGA compatibility. HDMI is backwards compatible with DVI because they have the same electrical specifications for their pin outs. The only concern I have is that the audio may or may not work. *Features specific to HDMI, such as remote-control and audio transport, are not available in devices that use legacy DVI-D signalling. However, many devices output HDMI over a DVI connector and some multimedia displays may accept HDMI (including audio) over a DVI input.* [Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HDMI#Compatibility_with_DVI)

Comment: I also used to use an DVI to HDMI cable on my PC.

Comment: @DrZoo that looks like sufficient info for you to post as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The adapter is all that you need. HDMI is backwards compatible with DVI because they have the same electrical specifications for their pin outs. So you'll be able to simply plug it in and be good to go.

The only concern I have is that the audio may or may not work.

> Features specific to HDMI, such as remote-control and audio transport, are not available in devices that use legacy DVI-D signalling. However, many devices output HDMI over a DVI connector and some multimedia displays may accept HDMI (including audio) over a DVI input.
>   [Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HDMI#Compatibility_with_DVI)

I also used an HDMI to DVI cable, virtually the same thing as an adapter, on my PC. In my case the carrying of audio did work fine. But this was coming from a DVI out port on an Nvidia GTX 680, to a new Samsung monitor.