# Are all DVI-D <-> HDMI cables bidirectional?

Tags: display, hdmi, dvi

I have a laptop with an HDMI 1.4 output. I awaiting delivery of a monitor that may have a DVI-D input (the Ebay description said DVI-D in one place and HDMI in another). I need a cable to connect them.

My understanding is that DVI-D and HDMI ports are always female and that [the video standards are the same](https://superuser.com/a/1163516/1006995). So am I right in thinking that I can buy any male-male cable/adapter advertised as either DVI-D to HDMI or HDMI to DVI-D?

For example, [this AmazonBasics cable](https://www.amazon.co.uk/AmazonBasics-Adapter-Cable-Latest-Standard-Black/dp/B014I8UQJY/ref=sr_1_10?dchild=1&keywords=HDMI%20to%20DVI-D&link_code=qs&qid=1592660755&sourceid=Mozilla-search&sr=8-10&tag=wwwcanoniccom-20) says that it "adapts a DVI-D output to an HDMI input", as though it is unidirectional. Is that just a misunderstanding or is it possibly correct?

The monitor probably doesn't have audio, so I am only worried about the video connection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can buy any adapter you like.

Cables and adapters (in this case) are passive, and just make electrical contact.

Comment: citation needed.

Comment: @ЯрославРахматуллин A simple lookup at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HDMI#Compatibility_with_DVI) would have given you the citation.